# Set Custom 'User Account Control Settings' UAC in Windows 10 Version 2004 OS Build: 19041.508

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac, notifications

I was wondering if there is a way to create custom UAC Settings on windows 10, Primarily to turn of Notification or warning when I click on `Run As Administrator` in the right click context menu. I followed the directions in this post [Disable UAC Notification](https://winaero.com/how-to-turn-off-and-disable-uac-in-windows-10/) but was unable to locate the setting in the normal Windows 10 Settings menu, It seem's that they have streamlined and removed alot of the functionality within the setting's but you can still access it through enableing GodMode Settings folder via => [GodMode](https://www.howtogeek.com/402458/enable-god-mode-in-windows-10/) Or Typeing UAC into the Search bar Which I only just found out..
Currently windows settings only have 4 options shown in the picture below:

[image]

The Four settings are available currently in windows are

1. Always Notify..[When] **Applications try to install Software or make changes to my computer** ....................................or **I make changes to windows settings**
2. Default **Don't notify me when I make Changes to windows Settings**
3. 3rd Option is almost Identical to No. 2
4. Never Notify **When Applications try to install Software or make changes to my computer or I make changes**

They haven't left you very much control over how this option works,
I wish to Always be notified if a program or outside source trys to install software or change settings But also never be notified If i try to run a program or CMD in Administrator mode, Is there a way to possibly do this either through the registry, Event Manager or custom script/batch file...

I have tried all of the settings and none of them disable notifications when you try and run batch files as an administrator or opening up Bleachbit.. Except for the Very bottom Option, But then this leaves the PC open to Malware or Virus Attacks either on the web, downloading software or through bittorrent downloads.. UAC is still available by going through the Custom setting folder mentioned in the 2nd link, then scroll down to Security and Maintenance 2nd option in that group. All the previous questions Are based around windows 7 & windows 8.1 none up to date nor are any of the Articles I have read Related to the latest versions of windows 10.. They are all old articles that have completely different setting menu and UI... Anyone know how to solve this?

Other Questions and Article relating to UAC =>
[Broken UAC cant edit file folders](https://superuser.com/questions/668555/broken-uac-cant-edit-file-folders-or-change-settings-in-user-account?rq=1)
[Windows 10 UAC Promt Default to particular Admin User](https://superuser.com/questions/1375527/windows-10-uac-prompt-default-to-particular-admin-user?rq=1)
[Find out what Changes the Settings for UAC All the Time](https://superuser.com/questions/1062978/find-out-what-does-change-the-settings-for-user-account-control-all-the-time?rq=1)
[Microsoft Docs for UAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works)
[Microsoft Docs For UAC & AMSI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/amsi/antimalware-scan-interface-portal)
[HackerNews UAC Bypass](https://latesthackingnews.com/tag/windows-uac-bypass/)
[Why does UAC Still Prompt me when Run As Administrator is permanently Set](https://superuser.com/questions/350632/why-does-uac-still-prompt-me-when-run-as-administrator-is-permanently-set?rq=1)
[Windows 10 UAC Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/980751/windows10-uac-pop-up?rq=1)

I have Found four referances to UAC in the Windows registry:
1)[image]
2)[image]
3)[image]
4)

Mainly posting this question for my own Interest and research, Will update the links and images in a minute. Please don't edit or delete it without commenting or Adding a valid answer..

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what you may wish to try with GodMode, the settings that exist now have existed since the beginning of Windows 10 (and even back into Windows 7/8).

There is no increased native granularity available.

I actually believe the settings work well.

True Administrators need only click OK.

Settings need to be ON for the Store to work correctly.

So native settings actually work well.

Comment: I don't use the Windows store, ever.. I only installed the GodMode folder option, because I found it Very difficult To navigate the new Settings UI when I upgraded to windows 10 & Could not find half the setting that I was used to previously.. Personally i think they should seperate the two forms of notifications one for `Other programs` & one for `User changes`.. Bundleing them together seems counter-intuitive.= But just my opinion..

Comment: Plus constantly having to click Ok, & have it refresh my Desktop with an annoying tone... Is exactly that. Annoying.

Comment: Other people do so settings are for the majority. If you do not like the sound, it exists in Control Panel, Sound, Sounds tab. Turn the sound for Windows User Account Control OFF. That works. If you are Admin and use Next to bottom, screen does not refresh  (for me)

Comment: I've Changed the Sound to a less annoying one as per your Suggestion, But that still does not answer the question whether it is possible to get more granular control either programatically or by any other means..

Comment: There is not any way I know of to change the granularity of the UAC settings. The main settings have been there for a very long time and I have not seen any move to change.